# FBSDK Get User's friend who authorized the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

How can I get user's friends (from his access token) who authorized the app as well?

```
$ https://graph.facebook.com/<uid>/friends?access_token=<token>
{"data":[]}
```

I have two friends using my app and we are all receiving an empty array.
Am I missing something ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: did both users authorize the app with user_friends? did you try with /me/friends?

Comment: Thanks that was it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make this work, both users (you and your friend) need to authorize the app with the `user_friends` permission. You can also use `/me/friends` btw.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I needed to add the following in my `LoginButton`: `readPermissions={["email","public_profile","user_friends"]}`